# Does the double slit interference pattern depend upon probability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference, wave-particle-duality, superposition

If the interference pattern depends upon the probability of the particles travelling through the slit then the intensity at any point on the graph must not be zero. But graphs show that the intensity can reach zero. How???!

Comment: Please answer it quickly 

Comment: The interference pattern doesn't depend on the probability of the particles passing through the slits. It depends on the sum of the wavefunctions from the particles passing through the slits. If the wavefunctions sum to zero at a point then the probability of find a particle at that point is zero and hence the intensity is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The calculated double slit interference pattern for a single photon predicts the probability that (all of) its energy will be absorbed (by a detector or reflector) at any selected point in the pattern.  The pattern itself can only be observed by using a large number of photons.  The wave packet associated with each photon must pass through both slits.